# Remove and disable systemdi process in linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Hello  how can I delete and permanently block this process?

```
PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
8243 mario      20   0 1303M  879M 41716 S 142. 11.2  0:18.92 /usr/bin/systemdi -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -i :0 -r 60 -vcodec libx264 -f flv
```

Comment: is that actually about [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: is my pc compromised?

Comment: You tell me. Do you know why you have this process running?

Comment: Also, the name looks as if it was part of systemd, but it is not, it has the command line arguments of ffmpeg. My best guess is that your system is compromised.

Comment: @GAD3R I can't find any (relevant) reference to `systemdi` online...?